# Fetch url of html page inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, innerhtml

I am trying to fetch url hosted inside an iframe: **`document.getElementById('iframe').location.contentWindow.location.href`** .

I am getting an error saying (DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://Google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at :1:31).

I read about the cross origin where we can change the location of content inside iframe but can't access it (https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication). Also when I switch from "https://binge.com" to other link then url of contentWindow must change. But since I am not able to access that how can I access the changed url or add an event listener for changing DOM events.

The viewer would going through multiple sites and I want to store url of each last visited site the user goes inside the iframe.

I am new to javascript, any leads would be helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You cannot - for security reasons

Comment: Thanks mplungjan. But I need save url  hosted inside my iframe which gets changed when user goes through multiple sites in that inframe when there is a cross-origin issue.  Is there a way we can do it?

Comment: No. You might be able to use a proxy, but without such a thing (which is not trivial) you will not be able to monitor surf behaviour